# Java StackOverFlowError in QuickSort Algorithm

Tags: java

Whenever I test my QuickSort algorithm with more than ~6500 elements, I obtain a stack overflow error. How could I optimize my algorithm so I wouldn't get this error? As part of a requirement, my code must result to insertion sort if the partition size is less than the MIN_SIZE.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
       void quickSort(T[] array, int first, int last)
    {
        if (last - first + 1 < MIN_SIZE)
        {
            insertionSort(array, first, last);
        }
        else {
            if (first < last)
            {
                // create the partition: Smaller | Pivot | Larger
                int pivotIndex = partition(array, first, last);
              
                // sort subarrays Smaller and Larger
                quickSort(array, first, pivotIndex-1);
                quickSort(array, pivotIndex+1, last);
            } // end if
        }
    }  // end quickSort
```

Here is the code for partitioning the array:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
            int partition(T[] a, int first, int last)
        {
            int pivotIndex = last;  // simply pick pivot as rightmost element
            T pivot = a[pivotIndex];
        
            // determine subarrays Smaller = a[first..endSmaller]
            //                 and Larger  = a[endSmaller+1..last-1]
            // such that elements in Smaller are <= pivot and 
            // elements in Larger are >= pivot; initially, these subarrays are empty
        
            int indexFromLeft = first; 
            int indexFromRight = last - 1; 
        
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                // starting at beginning of array, leave elements that are < pivot; 
                // locate first element that is >= pivot
                while (a[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
                    indexFromLeft++;
        
                // starting at end of array, leave elements that are > pivot; 
                // locate first element that is <= pivot
        
                while (a[indexFromRight].compareTo(pivot) > 0 && indexFromRight > first)
                    indexFromRight--;
        
                // Assertion: a[indexFromLeft] >= pivot and 
                //            a[indexFromRight] <= pivot.
        
                if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight)
                {
                    swap(a, indexFromLeft, indexFromRight);
                    indexFromLeft++;
                    indexFromRight--;
                }
                else 
                    done = true;
            } // end while
        
            // place pivot between Smaller and Larger subarrays
            swap(a, pivotIndex, indexFromLeft);
            pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;
        
            // Assertion:
            // Smaller = a[first..pivotIndex-1]
            // Pivot = a[pivotIndex]
            // Larger  = a[pivotIndex + 1..last]
        
            return pivotIndex; 
        }  // end partition
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on a quick look, I can't see anything in the function that would make an excessively large stack frame. However a recursive function always has a limit because each call uses stack (local variables plus function arguments) for each call.

It does seem odd that you hit the limit at 6500, since a perfectly balanced tree should only take (log base 2) calls (about 12 or 13), unless your list is already sorted - quicksort is notoriously bad in that case, and could make 6500 calls then.

If this is an exercise, try selecting a random pivot, that should give you better balance. If you're looking for an actual sort, try something less recursive like a merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

Short basics on how programs in general work, and what leads to the `StackOverflowError`:

- The stack is where all the operations for the CPU lie in sequence, but you can add more elements (do this next) or remove elements (have done this, don't need it anymore)
- For each method you call, a new stack frame is put on top of the stack. This contains jumpback informations, and usually return values and parameters,
- - so you can pass information from the calling method to the called method
- - so when the called method is done, you know where to jump back to, to resume the former method
- if you call too many methods, the stack will become too big to fit in your RAM (the real-life restrictions are a LOT worse) so you cannot call the subsequent method, so the call fails.
- - now this is **especially** true for recursive methods, because their primary distinction from "normal" methods is to call themself over and over again (sort() calls sort() calls sort() etc).
- - there are also less direct method "recursion" loops, where *a() calls b()* and then *b() calls c()* and *c() calls a()* and *a() calls b()* etc

So the problem is that in your code, probably the sort() method, calls itself (either directly or via other methods), and this finally leads to the Error.

Check the stop condition when that method shall `return` without/before calling itself. That condition might be faulty.

Comment: This answer is too generic. The `quicksort` algorithm is known to be highly recursive _and_ known to be highly performing. If what you say is true, people would shy away from quicksort. Yet this is not the case. Quicksort is known to be one of the best algorithms, even for large amounts of data.

Comment: What you say is false: 1) How do you think method calling works? Ever implemented something in assembler? 2) If implemeted properly, for (big) N elements, the QS algorithm would only ~log2(N) steps. So, for an acceptable amount of elements, you can use QS without any problems. (Unless you messed with memory/stack settings) 3) You can write any QS algorithm in a non-recursive way, using a stack of their own. 4) Combined with #3, reliable QS algorithms often are combined with other algorithms to be more memory effective.

Comment: 5) I also said the problem probably lies in code we dont see, probably the stop condition. In the code itself we cannot see what the problem is, because the OP gave us too little detail. Also check johnbayko s post. And in addition, I already mentioned those problems, but @nimantha removed them (which is not good, because it goes against the quality recommendations we should stick to). So the OP should have given us more info in the first place, but didn't. That's why there still is no (and cannot be) proper solution.

Comment: Please don't comment about the question itself in your answer. Just stick to the solution.

Comment: @Dharman Looks like you haven't read or understood the problem. Try to solve it, then you'll see that we CANNOT even provide a solution to the problem, because important stuff is missing from the question. So, as usual on stackoverflow, the OP should provide mode details to the question. Removing that *essential* requirement will NOT improve Q or A

Comment: But you answered it. If it is missing details then you wouldn't be able to write an answer or even shouldn't attempt to write one.